# Gnome doesn't remmember my settings

Tags: 13.10, gnome

I recently upgradeed from Gnome shell 3.8 to 3.10. My problem now is each time I power on my computer I must enable my extensions. All the extension are disabled at start.

Someone has an idea of the origin of my problem?

Comment: I suggest using another DE until the bug is fixed.

Comment: @Fischer the bug is fixed on Gnome 3.12 but I don't know how to upgrade to that version.

Comment: gnome 3.12 won't work on ubuntu 13.10, they won't bother backporting it, you could just go for ubuntu 14.04 http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/gnome-3-12-ubuntu-gnome-devs-explain

Comment: I can't install 14.04 right now the upgrade manger is not working for me. I don't want to do a fresh install the last time I did it took me days to set it up (I had graphics card drivers errors). I searched and I found that I can enable the extensions by using a script that run at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, its a bug, but it can be solved. When You Login, before entering password, their will be setting icon. Click that select another Session & now do some changes then reboot & see your settings will be saved. I had same issues.

Comment: I don't enter password at login.

Comment: Then do it temporarily. Go to System Settings > User Accounts > Unlock (enter password) > Automatic Login --ON then restart your pc thn follow above answer & do changes & reboot will find what you wanted & then turn Auotomatic login --OFF. If you find it helpful then mark answer as Correct! :)

Comment: I tried like you said, I disabled Automatic login but it has no effect (I entered my session without entering the password) but the extensions are enabled.

Comment: The second I rebooted I was asked to enter the passwrod. Your solution worked for me but when I enabled automatic login my extensions are disabled again.

Comment: From now on your settings will be saved. This time enable extensions you like, on next reboot you wont find it to reset. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is no bug any more (date of 26th January 2017). You simply go to execute this by:

Alt-F2

Then you type into line :

gnome-session-properties

Then Window pops up, where you can make entries for your programs to
be saved in a session, when logging out and logging back after reboot.

As command you need to know, where program is located, just an example:

You want to put in gnome-terminal, type as name "Terminal" and as command

set in:

/usr/bin/gnome-terminal

For each wished program you usually need the command which is mostly beginning with /usr/bin/name-of-program.

Comment: @Hunsu - have actualized your question with my answer, because answer of Deepen is not suiting to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS2.